# String rotator in C++ (bitwise rotation)

Tags: c++, string, rotation

I have string array which has 8 field. 8 bits per field give me 64 bits of memory in single string this type. I want to create rotate function for this string array. For simple for string `20` (in HEX) function `RotateLeft(string, 1)` gives me 40, like in rotate. Max rotate value is 64, then function must return sent string (`RotateLeft(string, 64) == string`). I need rotate left and right. I try to create something like this:

```
std::string RotateLeft(std::string Message, unsigned int Value){
    std::string Output;
    unsigned int MessageLength = Message.length(), Bit;
    int FirstPointer, SecondPointer;
    unsigned char Char;

    for (int a = 0; a < MessageLength; a++){
        FirstPointer = a - ceil(Value / 8.);
        if (FirstPointer < 0){
            FirstPointer += MessageLength;
        }
        SecondPointer = (FirstPointer + 1) % MessageLength;

        Bit = Value % 8;
        Char = (Message[FirstPointer] << Bit) | (Message[SecondPointer] & (unsigned int)(pow(2, Bit) - 1));
        Output += Char;
    }
    return Output;
}
```

It working for value 64, but not for other values. For simple for HEX string (function get string elements as decimal values but it is for better reading) when I sent this value: `243F6A8885A308D3` and execute `RotateLeft(string, 1)` I received `A6497ED4110B4611`. When I check this in Windows Calc it now valid value. Anyone can help me and show where I do mistake?

Comment: Did I get it right, that you have hex numbers that are stored as string and you want to rotate the hex value (and not the actual characters in the string)?

Comment: @tobi303 No, hex values is only preview. I convert this values to dec.

Comment: Then I am confused, because `20` rotated as a string is not `40`.

Comment: @tobi303 rotation left is not multiply by 2? Oh no

Comment: Another point that causes me confusion is that you mention a string array in the beginning but I dont see any array in the code

Comment: if you rotate a string `abcdef` by 2 you get `cdefab`

Comment: @tobi303 I don't want rotate chars, I want rotate bits. Sorry, I forget about it. If I want to rotate chars I should use `std::rotate()` or something like that. I know it, I can search and I don't stupid :)

Comment: Why not just convert it to a number, rotate it and convert it back to a string?

Comment: @Ben which number can contain 64 bits? Unsigned long int?

Comment: @ventaquil yep. depending on the architecture.

Comment: @ventaquil `uint64_t` can

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I will try do this :)

Comment: if your platform does not support 64 bit types, you may use `std::bitset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a hex value in a string, you want to rotate it as if it was actually a number. You could just change it to an actual number, then back into a string:

```
// Some example variables.
uint64_t x, shift = 2; 
string in = "fffefffe", out;

// Get the string as a number
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << in;
ss >> x;

// Shift the number
x = x << shift;

// Convert the number back into a hex string 
std::ostringstream ss2;
ss2 << std::hex << x;

// Get your output.
out = ss2.str();
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/Uk8F5W)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I correctly understand what you want to do, but somehow to me it looks like you are doing something rather simple in a complicated way. When shifting numbers, I would not put them in a string. However, once you have it as a string, you could do this:

```
std::string rotate(std::string in,int rot){
    long long int number;
    std::stringstream instream(in);
    instream >> number;
    for (int i=0;i<rot;i++){number *= 2;}
    std::stringstream outstream;
    outstream << number;
    return outstream.str();
}
```

...with a small modification to allow also negative shifts.

Comment: Maybe mention modifications to allow 64 bit numbers as well. This was part of the Question.